# SQL Server 2008R2 sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats - unusual last execution time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a job which captures data from sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats.
The job runs every minute. It is a straight insert from, no joins.
I'm have a scenario where, quite regularly ( exactly the same two days every week without fail) one particular object id returns something like below

```
timeOfCapture /LastExecutionTime

16:58 / 16:30

16:59 / 16:30

17:00 / 16:30

17:01 / 17:00       (no explanation)

17:02 / 16:30       (no explanation - back to normal)

17:03 / 16:30
```

The stored procedure is invoked by a job which started around 16:30
The stored procedure did NOT run at 17:00 (as far as I know).
There is a job which starts at 17:00 but does not execute this stored procedure.
The stored procedure takes about 30 seconds to complete.

the object id is the same for all, the database id is also the same.

The fact this occurs regularly without fail means perhaps there is another process

I don't know if there's anything going on like reboots etc
I'm also not sure if there is an external process ( other server/ excel/etc)  that maybe invokes the stored procedure, or maybe there's a rollback.

thid could be a red herring, something I've overlooked, but I've checked everything I can think of.
Any ideas on those LastExecutionTimes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That DMV contains one row for each **cached** stored procedure **plan**, and the lifetime of the row is as long as the stored procedure remains cached. This means that a stored procedure can have **multiple** rows in this table, or none at all if they don't have a plan in cache. The `last_execution_time` corresponds to the last time that procedure was executed with the query plan for that row. So, in your case, the procedure could have been executed at 1630 on a previous day (since you didn't show the date) and then 1700 on the current day, or visa versa.  Given the repeat-ability of your scenario, your current job is likely using one plan, and another job (even on another day) is using another plan. It's unclear how you are choosing which row to insert... perhaps `TOP 1` without an `ORDER BY`. This could cause this behavior. We'd need to see insert statement that is doing the *logging*

Note that there are many things that could cause the plan to get removed from cache or a new one created. The latter is less likely in a Job with fixed parameters.

If you really want to track the execution of the procedure (not only the last execution of a cached plan), you'll need to set up a logging mechanism. [Aaron has a good article on it her](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2003/simple-process-to-track-and-log-sql-server-stored-procedure-use/)e.

Comment: Hi , thanks for your reply. Its all on the same day. There is no other job which calls this procedure. I've proved this by modifying the procedure to write to a log table. 

Also, as mentioned, i'm not choosing a row to insert. It is a straight insert

i.e

INSERT mytable SELECT * FROM  sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats

Comment: There can still be multiple plans for that proc. Can you check on that?

Comment: Just checked, there are no other plans for that proc.

Comment: INSERT [myCapture]
        ([database_id]
        ,[object_id]
        ,[type]
        ,[type_desc]
        ,[sql_handle]
        ,[plan_handle]
        ,[cached_time]
        ,[last_execution_time]
        ,[execution_count]
        , etc )
select [database_id]
           ,[object_id]
           ,[type]
           ,[type_desc]
           ,[sql_handle]
           ,[plan_handle]
           ,[cached_time]
           ,[last_execution_time]
           ,[execution_count]
           , etc
from sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats

Comment: sorry man, i can't reproduce this. i find it hard to believe there is only 1 plan if the plan cache isn't being flushed

Comment: I'd have thought it was perfectly normal to have no more than one instance of a stored procedure in this view, Maybe you're confusing this with sys.dm_exec_cached_plans / sys.dm_exec_sql_text / ys.dm_exec_query_plan 
? Either way, I actually think it's a bug. Thanks for all your help, appreciate it.